# How to store a video file either in .ts or mp4 in flutter that is only accessible from app

Tags: flutter, dart

we want to store videos for offline view from the app but we don't want users to watch the video from gallery or from their apps. Also if they get easy direct access, they may share elsewhere. So we want a system to encrypt the file or lock the folder where we store the .ts or mp4 so that they cannot access it manually and only the app can do it.

Is there anyways to achieve this with flutter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the file in Applications documents directory. Its only accessible by your app. use your preferred encryption depending your security concern. use the package [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) to use the function `final Directory appDocumentsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();`